# Programmaticaly disable existing button in outlook compose window ribbon

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, addin-express

Am writing an outlook add-in in c#. I would like to disable the "Permissions" button in the "Options" tab while composing a new email.

Am currently using Addin express for creating the outlook add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `command` tag with the `getEnabled` attribute defined. For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Permissions"  getEnabled="OnGetEnabled" />
  </commands>
 </customUI>
```

You can repurpose built-in ribbon controls, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

The list of built-in control IDs can be found in the following documents:

- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)